# In XPages, how do you import one SSJS library into another?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

As the title says, is there any way to import one SSJS library into another?  I have a debugging library named debug.jss that I would like to include and use in my other SSJS libraries, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  It seems like a pretty fundamental question, but I haven't found any answer.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the first line;

```
import debug;
```

It will import the second SSJS library.

The related documentation is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_elements_statements_import_r.html).

Comment: I had tried this, but sadly and embarrassingly, I misspelled the library name and thought the obscure error was because you can't use import like that.  Thanks for clearing that up!